# Symfony1.4 and Doctrine1.2 setting and getting child elements in execution time

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I'm using Symfony1.4 and Doctrine1.2 to create children objects and print them in execution time. The problem is that I always get the children objects from the first query.

I have the following schema:

```
Parent:
  id
  name

Child:
  id
  parent_id
  name
```

My operations:

1. Initially I have **one** *Parent* (with id=1), and  **no** *Child*
2. I grab a *Parent* (id=1) and store that object on `$parent`
3. List it's Child objects
4. Result: `none` **OK: as expected**
5. Create a new *Child* and set it's parent to `1`
6. List `$parent`'s *Child* objects
7. Result: `none` **OOPS: I expected the new Child from 5.!**

Code:

```php
$parent = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Parent p')->where('p.id = ?', 1)->limit(1)->fetchOne(); /* from 2. */
print_r($parent->getChild()->toArray()); /* from 3. */
$child = new Child();
$child->setParentId($parent->getId());
$child->save(); /* from 4. */
print_r($parent->getChild()->toArray()); /* from 6. */
```

I've already tried re-grabbing the $parent before the last line, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around for this issue:

```php
$parent = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Parent p')->where('p.id = ?', 1)->limit(1)->fetchOne();
print_r($parent->getChild()->toArray()); 
$child = new Child();
$child->setParentId($parent->getId());
$child->save(); 
$parent->refresh(true); /* see note! */
print_r($parent->getChild()->toArray());
```

**Note, from Doctrine's comments:**

```
/**
* refresh
* refresh internal data from the database
*
* @param bool $deep                        If true, fetch also current relations. Caution: this deletes
*                                          any aggregated values you may have queried beforee
*
* @throws Doctrine_Record_Exception        When the refresh operation fails (when the database row
*                                          this record represents does not exist anymore)
* @return boolean
*/
```